# Difficulty serializing dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, drop-down-menu

Basically I have a number of forms on my page and I'd like to be able to access them all at once and add them to one large get request. It's largely working, but I'm having some trouble getting it working with drop down menus since their markup is different from other forms (at least in the examples I've seen). Please bear with me since I'm new to front-end development, but this is what I've got thus far:

```
    <form id="sorting" class="auto-submit" action="/search" method="get">
        <select id="sorting" class="parameter" action="/search" method="get">
            % if previous.get("sorting", "false") == "relevance":
                <option selected="selected" name="sort" value="relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option name="sort" value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
            % elif previous.get("sorting", "false") == "alphabetical":
                <option name="sort" value="relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option name="sort" selected="selected" value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
            % else:
                <option name="sort" value="relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option name="sort" value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
            % endif
        </select>
    </form>
```

The script I'm currently using to try to access these values (launched from elsewhere, but I don't think that's the issue):

```
function submitForms(retain_page) {
    var get_data = [];
    var form_list = $(".auto-submit .parameter");
    for (var i in form_list){
        get_data.push.apply(get_data, form_list.eq(i).serializeArray());
    }
    var url = document.URL.split("?")[0]+"?";
    for (var o in get_data){
        if (retain_page === false){
            if (get_data[o].name == "page"){
                get_data[o].value = 1;
            }
        }
        url = url + (get_data[o].name + "=" +get_data[o].value + "&");
    }
    document.location.href = url.substring(0, url.length-1);
}
```

I'm pretty certain the issue is in how I'm accessing the element, and in the javascript console I was able to get what I was looking for by running the following:

```
$(".auto-submit .parameter").eq(4).val()
```

And when I try serializing the same element I get an empty response which makes me think it somehow isn't realizing that it should be submitted in the form, but I'm kind of at a loss for where exactly I should define it. Sorry if this is a silly question, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to serialize this, but I assume this is indicative of deeper problems in my coding style so I won't accept this for some time and am totally open to other answers.

When I gave the select element a name everything suddenly worked. For reference here's the updated code:

```
 <form id="sorting" class="auto-submit" action="/search" method="get">
        <select name="sort" id="sorting" class="parameter" action="/search" method="get">
            % if previous.get("sort", "false") == "relevance":
                <option selected="selected" value="relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
            % elif previous.get("sort", "false") == "alphabetical":
                <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
            % else:
                <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
            % endif
        </select>
    </form>
```